# How to get child theme module templates to override main module template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, divi

For some reason my child theme templates are not being recognized.

I believe I have followed the correct procedure (and checked for caching etc)

```
/wp-content/themes/divi-child/includes/builder/module/Blog.php
```

should replace

```
/wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/module/Blog.php
```

(same path and same file with a slight update)

The child theme module template is not recognized (changes to the child theme template have no effect)

> I have tested editing the main file and this works immediately every
> time.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Cheers

---

EDIT

The below should work according to Divi however it breaks the site when I try.

Apparently it is not enough to just copy the module into the child theme. The file needs to be duplicated. Then copied file to child-theme/custom-modules/Blog.php. After adding following code to the bottom of the functions.php file:

```
function divi_custom_blog_module() {
get_template_part( '/custom-modules/Blog' );
$myblog = new custom_ET_Builder_Module_Blog();
remove_shortcode( 'et_pb_blog' );
add_shortcode( 'et_pb_blog', array( $myblog, '_render' ) );
}
add_action( 'et_builder_ready', 'divi_custom_blog_module' );
```

Comment: I see, in the guide - they said you need to put your blog template file to: /wp-content/themes/divi-child/custom-modules/. And later add the codes to bottom of your child theme's functions.php file. Is that what you did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few other steps https://intercom.help/elegantthemes/en/articles/4532734-moving-blog-module-in-child-theme

1. Create a new folder in the child theme folder, for example, includes folder.
2. Now copy the  Divi/includes/builder/module/Blog.php  file from the parent theme into the  child-theme/includes/  folder.
3. Open up the  Blog.php   file of your child theme and replace this line (at the very top):

```
    require_once 'helpers/Overlay.php';
        
    class ET_Builder_Module_Blog extends ET_Builder_Module_Type_PostBased {
```

with:

```
    get_template_part( '/includes/builder/module/helpers/Overlay.php' );
    
    class custom_ET_Builder_Module_Blog extends ET_Builder_Module_Type_PostBased {
```

Replace:  $this->vb_support = 'on';   with  $this->vb_support = 'off';

Remove this line from the bottom: new ET_Builder_Module_Blog();

4. Finally, add the following code to the functions.php file in your child theme folder:

```
/*================================================

#Load custom Blog  Module

================================================*/

function divi_custom_blog_module() {

    get_template_part( '/includes/Blog' );

    $myblog = new custom_ET_Builder_Module_Blog();

    remove_shortcode( 'et_pb_blog' );

    add_shortcode( 'et_pb_blog', array( $myblog, '_render' ) );

}

add_action( 'et_builder_ready', 'divi_custom_blog_module' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got this issue similar to this before. I think - maybe the blog template is called by another file in the "father theme" folder some thing like:

```
$url = dirname(__FILE__)."/includes/builder/module/Blog.php";
```

this will cause the issue. to fix this there are two way:

#1: find and edit the file wich is call the blog template (not recommend)

#2: find and copy the file wich is call the blog template to your child theme (you can try with index.php, content.php or single.php first) (recommend)

Comment: Apparently there are extra steps - see below: